Create JSON request payload from extracted values inside ForEach controller
I have a list of countries using them I created my var_ variables to be used in ForEach loop controller

For Each Loop - Output variable countryName

Inside the ForEach loop controller - I have a JSON Extractor which is fetching the countryId,CurrencyId,countryCode on the basis of countryNames(output variable)

I want to create my JSON using these extracted values . But the problem is I am unable to retain the list of values extracted as every time the loop runs the values reset to the most recent value . I want to use the List of values here that I can use to create my JSON payload request .


Don't use JMeter Variables like ${currencyId} in Groovy scripts, use vars shorthand for JMeterVariables class instance like:
vars.get('currencyId')

As per JSR223 Sampler documentation:

The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:

Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
When using this feature, ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement. Instead use script parameters.


More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?
